# Preserving corners while stretching border image usging qt stylesheet

Tags: qt, stylesheet, slice, css

I'm using Qt 4.7 and trying to apply Qt stylesheets to my application.
As mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image) with the help of border-image you can stretch image with corners left "as is". Here is a [good example](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) of how that should work. Unfortunately I'm unable to get the same result. Instead of preserved corners I'm getting cutted and repeated middle part of the image.
Is there any mistakes in my code or its not implemented in Qt? (button added to MainWindow via gui designer).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyleSheet( "QPushButton{ border-image: url(:/border-image-marked.png) 25 30 10 20 repeat repeat; }" );

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Image taken from example above. [Direct link](http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border-image.png) to it.

p.s. It works well in QML's [BorderImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-borderimage.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply your styleSheet to a non-present QPushButton.

According to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image-prop only the following elements support this CSS property:

> This property is supported by QAbstractItemView subclasses,
>   QAbstractSpinBox subclasses, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QFrame, QGroupBox,
>   QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QRadioButton,
>   QSplitter, QTextEdit and QToolTip.

Comment: I'm trying to apply ["border-image"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image-prop) property, not "background".  and documentation states that QPushButton supports it. And I need it to work with all buttons, so using QApplication::setStyleSheet().

Comment: Hi @vkjr. As I already wrote in my message, QPushButton is one of the supported items. The link was wrong (copy-paste error). I never said it wasn't supported. However the problem here is different; you're trying to apply it to a non-existing QPushButton. There isn't any in your code. You did not create a QPushButton to apply the stylesheet to. You first need to create it, then apply it.

Comment: Button belongs to MainWindow, added with UI designer. I didn't mention this because thought that is pretty obvious.

Comment: @vkjr, it's not really obvious since it's not in your code. Conduct here is rather explicit. You need to show your full codebase regarding the issue so that we can help. Also it would be useful if you provided an image of the issue and what you wish to have.