# How to perserve border-image's corner as it is while stretch other parts in qt stylesheet?

Tags: qt, stylesheet

Duplicate:[An unsolveded question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969877/preserving-corners-while-stretching-border-image-usging-qt-stylesheet).

The question above is posted about 1 year ago,but no appropriate answer is posted.Now I encountered the same problem.

Comment: Can you post your code, the result you get, and the result you expect?

Comment: @thuga What I actually want to achieve is that keep a certain image 's corner **as it is** while other parts can zoom in or zoom out to fill widget's background.Sometimes image's corners are **elaborate** that it become **ugly** when it zoom in or zoom out. `border-image:url(:/Resources/item_back.png) 1 2 3 4 stretch stretch;` I don't konw how to set the middle four numbers to achieve my goal.Am I make myself understood?

Comment: The four numbers represent slicing. The order is top, right, bottom, left. Measure the borders of your image, and set those values. It's pretty well explained [here](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/).

Comment: @thuga Thanks!Now I figured it out.Besides,I forgot that **border-radius** could also effect corner details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[understanding border-image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) describes well.We can set the middle four numbers of the shorthand rule,which described like `border-image:url(:/Resources/item_back.png) 1 2 3 4 stretch stretch;` to proper value to make all your image corner's details as it is.